# Get words between string of url with php

Tags: php

I want to select specific words of an url. Let say I have an url localhost/index.php?exam=one&people=two

The question, how to get "one" and "two" with php? I was read preg_match function, but I still confuse with regulation expression pattern. thanks for advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$query - parse_url('localhost/index.php?exam=one&people=two', PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $keys);

print_r(array_values($keys)); // <- what you want
```

But beware of magic quotes in PHP < 5.4, [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) is affected by this setting

Answer (score 3):

Use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to access the query string of the URL. [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the query string on ampersands to get an array of `name=value` pairs and explode those parts on equal-signs to split them into name and value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parse_str()`, like this:

```
$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
parse_str($queryString, $parsedQueryString);

print_r($parsedQueryString);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['exam']` retrieves one

`$_GET['people']` retrieves two

Answer (score 0):

Those are called GET parameters. You can access them using php's hashed variable `$_GET['param']`.

In this case `$_GET['exam']` would be equal to 'one'

Answer (score 0):

Luckily PHP parses it for you!

Try:

```
echo $_GET['exam'];
```

to see how it works.

To help debug things, you might find:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

useful.

Answer (score 0):

you have this in the url? Then you can use `$_GET['exam']` and `$_GET['people']`. You can read more about this [here](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php)